# Can a disk partition have another nested inside it?

Tags: linux, partition, hard-disk, gpt, mbr

I am trying to better understand disks, partitions, and partition tables (mbr vs gpt). In the process I checked the disks on one of my machines (single boot ubuntu 20.04), and found that all of my disks are gpt. However I also found out that some of the partitions have a partition table too. What got me even more confused is that the `/boot/efi` partition is mbr even though it is on a disk that is gpt. At that point I wasn't sure whether the disk was gpt or otherwise so I tried to convert the `/boot/efi` to gpt but in the process ended up rendering my machine unbootable. When I looked online for how to convert between the two styles I found that the conversion is done on the disk rather than the partition, but I already have my disk partitioned as gpt. So my question can be divided into three parts (and it all depends on my understanding as laid out above being correct):

1- What does it even mean to have a partition table inside a partition?

2- How can a disk be gpt but the `/boot/efi` partition on it be mbr? And why?

3- If a system has two hard disks, but one operating system, can each one of these disks have their own different partition tables (one mbr the other gpt)?

Comment: I can answer the 3rd question: Yes, it's perfectly possible. For example some BIOS servers have mbr as boot partition, in order to boot, but GPT data disks, so that these data disks can be greater than 2TB (mbr limit). Also I'll present you another option which I use occasionally: Disks with no partition table or partitions! It's the loop kind, parted's terminology.

Comment: I see. So a partition is not really necessary for disks that don't have an os installed on them. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: For what it's worth, a partitioning system like MBR or GPT is just a way to seperate a single continuous region of a storage device into multiple continuous regions. Generally, you partition the physical device itself (i.e. the region encompassing the entire drive), but there's nothing stopping you from creating a GPT partition table on a partition and splitting it into several partitions. Of course, it probably wouldn't be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible.

"Instead of a primary partition, you can also define (exactly) one extended partition in the primary boot sector that contains all the disk space that is not allocated to any primary partition. In the extended partition further logical partitions can be set up, which in principle are structured in the same way as the primary partitions, with the difference that only the primary partitions can be booted directly. With a utility like Linux Loader (LILO), the operating system can be booted from any partition, even on other hard disks, but LILO itself must always be installed on a primary partition of the first hard disk."

Source: https://www.nextop.de/lhb/node231.html

Annotation:

The above example is not limited to the use of LiLo as boot manager.

It is to be noted that on a GPT hard disk no extended or logical partitions must be created, since the historical restriction of the number of primary partitions with old DOS and WINDOWS versions, do not exist here.

Comment: It's been years since I heard anyone talk about LiLo. And with GPT disks, extended partitions are mostly a thing of the past too, but what you say is technically correct.

Comment: Annotation:

The example is not limited to the use of LiLo as boot manager.

Comment: I didn't think (or meant to suggest) that, but that doesn't change that I haven't heard anyone talk about LiLo for years.

Comment: OSes treat primary + extended tables as a single thing, not separate nested things. extended partitions are a historical implementation detail. same thing with protective MBR outside of a GPT: it's part of it, not an independent nested structure. i don't know enough about extended tables (and don't care), but it might be the case that they are not identical to primary tables. if an extended table without its outer primary table is not a primary table itself, then they are not nested tables in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

> However I also found out that some of the partitions have a partition table too.

this is very unlikely. more likely, you are wrong. how did you arrive at this conclusion? what is objective evidence for this?

> What got me even more confused is that the /boot/efi partition is mbr

this sentence does not make sense. partition tables are GPT or MBR, not the partitions they contain. the partitions are binary blobs.

precisely because of this total freedom, a partition could contain a disk image with its nested partition table, but no software will create anything like this without being seriously strong-armed into doing it.

the partition that used to be mounted at /boot/efi in your system was likely a FAT32 partition, which served the purpose of an ESP (EFI System Partition). the ESP contains bootloaders that the UEFI firmware launches. UEFI is required to understand FAT, and for regular hardware, ESPs are always FAT.

> I tried to convert the /boot/efi to gpt but in the process ended up rendering my machine unbootable

it doesn't make sense to speak of converting a file system into a partition table. what you actually did is anybody's guess. the outcome is the expected one: your ESP used to contain the GRUB2 bootloader, which used to chainload Linux. you obliterated your bootloader, so obviously your computer couldn't boot anymore.

> When I looked online for how to convert between the two styles I found that the conversion is done on the disk rather than the partition, but I already have my disk partitioned as gpt.

obviously. and you disk was GPT already, so there was nothing to convert.

> 1- What does it even mean to have a partition table inside a partition?

inside a partition you can have any data at all. you typically have a file system, but you can put any odd stuff in it, including a straight dump of a popular Rick Astley video stream, or a straight dump of a disk image including its (then nested) partition table.

why would you do that? for the level of this conversation: no reason whatsoever. (more esoteric reasons exist: for instance, a partition could hold data for an emulated disk used in a VM, including of course its nested partition table.)

> 2- How can a disk be gpt but the /boot/efi partition on it be mbr? And why?

it wasn't, you are mistaken.

> 3- If a system has two hard disks, but one operating system, can each one of these disks have their own different partition tables (one mbr the other gpt)?

each disk can store any data you want, just like any partition can, including a straight file system without a partition table (like a floppy disk), a partition table and file system partitions (like a regular hard disk), nested partition tables, straight dumps of Astly videos, random noise, etc.

whether a particular OS will recognize the format and use the drive contents and what drivers does it require for that is another matter.

FWIW, all OSes I know will mount disks containing different partition schemes at the same time without issue, and if they didn't it would be considered a bug.

Comment: Note that a GPT partition scheme typically includes a "protective MBR" table which tells a MBR partition tool that the whole disk is reserved by GPT data. And inside this whole disk partition, a GPT table and the different GPT partitions.

Comment: There is actually an explanation for all of my observations above. The machine I was talking about was virtualised. But I like how you ask for "objective evidence" when you haven't provided a single reference for any of your "answers". Also saying it wasn't without explaining why, is not an answer mate. And back then I was preparing for my LFCA certificate. I happily "obliterated" many other VMs to understand how oses work. Take it easy bud!

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer what you say is partially correct. yes, a protective MBR PT is *part of* a GPT.  no, the GPT is *not inside* a partition of the protective MBR. (GPTs are not fractals :-p ) the GPT is the whole structure including the protective MBR: it has the MBR part and its other parts (which all lie inside the protective MBR partition, as you correctly noted). i know you know this, but the idea that there is a nested GPT inside the MBR as you sort of put it is confusing for people who don't know as much as you do. i hope you don't take offense by my being anal about it.

Comment: @cad86 you were wrong in your observation that an ESP (FAT filesystem) was also an MBR PT. by objective evidence i meant "what tool you ran that lead you to believe that", then maybe i could've explain why your assumption was wrong. in essence it's a case of bad question: instead of asking "how come an ESP is also a PT?", you could better have asked "i ran this tool on this setup, i got this output, i expected this other, what gives?" for better responses. FWIW, MBR and FAT can start with a sector that shares some properties (eg: boot signature), and that may have caused confusion.

Comment: but your question is what it is and i had to answer it in that form. regarding sources: you can check the specs of GPT and MBR (if it exists) to verify that they in general don't mandate what's inside partitions, but that is obvious. and you can look at the EFI/UEFI specs for info on what an ESP is and the mandated properties. but neither of these are good pointers: just search for "EFI System Partition" and you'll find load of resources for any level of detail you need.

Comment: Alright thanks @Lanchon. Unfortunately it has been almost three years since I posted this question so I cannot remember the exact tools I used. But I am fairly certain I used KVM for virtualisation. I will try to rerun the experiment from memory and post the exact details for verification. Thanks for the kind reply bud and for the pointers.

Comment: This response is overly aggressive and opinionated. Please re-write, considering if the information you are providing is of use in answering the question.